# How do I access random values from an array nested in a dictionary from plist file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

Basically I need to get a random letter and the points associated with that letter from a plist.
I'm honestly not sure I have my plist set up in the best possible way to do this, I've never worked with plist before:
[image]

As soon as I get this working I'm going to be adding C-Z into the plist with each letters associated points. I'm just created a basic word tile game to try and learn sprite kit.

So far I've been able to access the plist file but have not had any luck getting a random Letter and it's Points.I'm getting all kinds of errors with everything I try.

```
Here's my code so far to access the plist:
        NSString* fileName = @"letters.plist";
        NSString* filepath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        NSDictionary* lettersPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
        NSDictionary* letters = lettersPlist[@"letters"];
```

So how do I get a random letter and it's points from this plist? And is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get a random number between 0 and the number of items in your `letters` array, and take that info out. For example, continuing your code:

```
u_int32_t bound = (u_int32_t)[letters count];
NSDictionary* randomLetterInfo = letters[arc4random_uniform(bound)];
NSString* randomLetter = randomLetterInfo[@"Letter"];
NSString* points = randomLetterInfo[@"Points"]; // points are a string in your plist
```

Comment: Nice! I just did what you suggested and then had to change the letters pointer to a NSArray and that did the trick.

Comment: @Scotty Oh sorry, I didn't even see it was a `Dictionary` in your example code since it was an `Array` in your plist ;) Sorry about that

Comment: no problem at all. With the error that I received it was pretty obvious what I needed to do.